# ziparchive folders and files exlude the current folder

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have a folder with files and sub folders:

```
base_folder_name
  -folder_01
    -file_01
    -file_02
  -folder_02
    -file_01
    ....etc
```

When I zip the folder I get exactly that structure.

But I would like to exclude the main 'base_folder_name' folder from the zip so that when I extract the files the structure is:

```
-folder_01
    -file_01
    -file_02
  -folder_02
    -file_01
    ....etc
```

This is my code:

```
$rootPath = public_path() .'/storage/base_folder_name'; 
    //Initialize archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open(public_path() .'/storage/base_folder_name/'base_folder_name.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
            $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
        \RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file)
    {
        // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
        if (!$file->isDir()){
            // Get real and relative path for current file
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();      
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
            log::info($relativePath);
            // Add current file to archive
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: so $relativePath is showing up in your log without the 'base_folder_name' in it?

Comment: Yes, the log shows everything except the 'base_folder_name'